# jQuery addClass() not working at certain media queries

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, addclass, squarespace

If the page is loaded and the browser window is between `1100px` & `640px`, the following jQuery script works properly:

```
  $('#mobileMenu').click(function(){      
    if ($('body').hasClass('mobile-nav-open')) {
      $('body').removeClass('mobile-nav-open')
    } else {
      $('body').addClass('mobile-nav-open');
    };
  });
```

What this does is when `a#mobileMenu` is clicked, a class is added to `body` and the mobile nav menu slides in, then the class is removed and the mobile nav menu closes upon another click.

But if the page is loaded at `<=640px`, the class `.mobile-nav-open` never gets added onto the `body`. I cannot for the life of me figure out why it isn't working. This code is also being inserted through Squarespace's code injection into the footer. There's a lot of JS packed into the template that may be interfering, but I can't figure out how to override it. Anyone able to help me out? Any help is appreciated.

The site can be seen here: https://ryan-vandyke-4rks.squarespace.com/

This looks to be what I'm trying to override:

```
Y.use(function (a) {
  a.on("domready", function () {
    if (640 >= a.one("body").get("clientWidth")) a.one("#mobileMenu").on("click", function () {
        a.one("body").hasClass("mobile-nav-open") ? a.one("body").removeClass("mobile-nav-open") :
        (a.one("body").addClass("mobile-nav-open"), a.one("body.email-open") && a.one("body").removeClass("email-open"), a.one("body.desc-open") && a.one("body").removeClass("desc-open"))
    });
  })
});
```

Comment: Nothing to do with your problem, but why wouldn't you just use `$(document.body).toggleClass('mobile-nav-open');` instead of the `if/else`?

Comment: @jfriend00 sorry I didnt saw if condition

Comment: @jfriend00 Still isn't working :/ But thanks, I'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of add/remove class on click try below approach to add/remove class on `body` tag.

```
function addBodyClass(){
    if($(window).width() <= 640){
        $('body').addClass('mobile-nav-open');
    } else {
        $('body').removeClass('mobile-nav-open');
    }
}

$(window).on('load resize', function(){addBodyClass()})
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/YnRs2/2/)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for the solution but I need it to happen on click.